# Good tools for animated maps on a webpage

Tags: python, django, dictionary, geodjango

I want to present regions on a map inside a webpage. The region should be clickable and highlighted when hovered. I'am using django so I tend to orient towords matplotlib and other python tools.

There are interesting projects on the web:

- [thematic mapping](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2008/04/thematic-mapping-with-geojson.html)
- [polymaps](http://polymaps.org/ex/world.html)
- [geodjango](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geographic-data) seems complicated
- [this blog](http://danieljlewis.org/2010/09/15/drawing-maps-with-python/) shows a marvelous way of displaying data on maps using matplotlib and [descartes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes/1.0)

The problem is that i don't know where to finf the GeaJson data concerning contries and regions.

Does anyone has some advices not to loose too much tim with complicated applications.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely go with openlayers if it's just presentation.

Geodjango is handy for allowing admins to edit spatial data in the django admin, but by itself doesn't have much in the way of map presentation templates - you have to build them yourself (using openlayers) or try the olwidget django addon.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out the OpenLayers ( http://openlayers.org/ ) project -- it provides a framework for pretty much any kind of map display in the browser (and it's also what is used by polymaps for their client side implementation).

Links to free map service data can be found here: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Available+WMS+and+WFS+servers. You might also want to try the Google Maps API ( http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html ), although this won't allow clickable regions that are already in the map.